# Prove that if $S$ has a greatest element $b$, then $b = lubS$.

Tags: proof-verification, alternative-proof

Prove that if $S$ has a greatest element $b$, then $b = lubS$.

These are the definitions I used: 
Def. Given a partially ordered set ($P, \le$), then an element $b$ of a subset $S$ of $P$ is the greatest element of $S$ if $\forall s \in S, s \le b$. 
Def. $lubS$ is the unique number having the following properties: 
1) $\forall x \in S, x \le lubS$ 
2) *If*$\;\exists b' \in S \, s.t. \forall x \in S, x \le b', then \, lubS \le b' $

> Assume $s \in S$. 
>       Let $b \in S \,be \,s.t. \forall s \in S, s \le b$. 
>       Then b is an upper bound for S. So we have 1). 
>       Suppose by contradiction that $\exists b' \in S \,s.t. \forall x \in S, x \le b' \land b > b'$. 
>           Then $b \notin S$. This contradicts the fact that $b \in S$. 
>       Then $\exists b' \in S \,s.t. \forall x \in S, x \le b' \implies lubS \le b'$. So we have 2). 
>   Then $\forall s \in S, \exists b \in S, s \le b \implies b=lubS.\square$

Is my proof complete and correct? What other ways are there to prove this? I have seen other lub proofs that are similar but vary slightly in the second property. For example, they use 2) as "if $M' < M, then\, \exists x \in E \,s.t. x > M'$." My textbook uses the theorem

> If $M$ is the least upper bound of the set $S$ and $\epsilon$ is a positive number, then there is at least one number $s$ in $S$ such that $M - \epsilon < s \le M$.

and then proves things like the $lubS = 3$ where $S=\{0,1,2,3\}$ by taking $\epsilon = 0.0001$ and $3 - 0.0001 < s \le 3$. I am not convinced fully of this because I have seen other proofs that do this for arbitrary positive $\epsilon$.

Can someone explain to me the differences/similarities among these definitions? What is the most appropriate/general approach to proving least upper and greatest lower bounds?
Thanks.

EDIT 
The correct definition for $lubS$ is 
Def. $lubS$ is the unique number having the following properties: 
1) $\forall x \in S, x \le lubS$ 
2) *If*$\;\exists b' \in \mathbb{R} \, s.t. \forall x \in S, x \le b', then \, lubS \le b' $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, be careful with the definition of a LUB of a set $S$ - this is not necessarily an element of $S$ itself. Think of the partial order $([0,1],\leq)$ with $S=[0,1)$.

However, in the case that $S$ has a maximal element $b$ it is true that $b=LUB(S)$. Your proof is essentially correct, but you should remove the assumption $b'\in S$ since this is not necessary.

Your second definition of the LUB is less general than the first, this time for the particular case that your set $S$ is some subset of the real line. But the concept of a LUB is much broader. For more information on all this look on wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it should be $b' \in \mathbb{R}$. However for the definition of the GLB, is it correct to say
GLB(S) is the unique number having the following properties: 
1) $\forall x \in S, GLB(S) \le x$ 
2) If $\exists b' \in S \,s.t. \forall x \in S, b' \le x, then \,GLB(S) \ge b'$ 

noting this time $b'$ is an element of $S$?

Comment: Exactly the same situation holds for the GLB: It need not be in $S$ itself, so the assumption $b'\in S$ is too restrictive.

Comment: Thanks, I must have copied down my notes incorrectly.